# When I console log redux store data it gets logged 4 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux and redux-thunk to store my data from API calls and everything is working fine, but when I get data in a component from my redux store and log it on console it gets logged 4 times, 2 times previous data (empty array) and 2 times new data, I don't know why it is happening and how to resolve this, kindly help.

Here is my component code, I am getting all 250 countries' data in this component and displaying country names and flags. On line 15 console log I get this on the console.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Row, Col, Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllCountries } from "../redux/actions";

const AllCountries = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { allCountries, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.getCountriesData
  );

  console.log(allCountries);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCountries());
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="center-div">
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner animation="border" variant="light" className="margin" />
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {allCountries.map((country) => {
            return (
              <Col key={country.name} sm={4}>
                <Link
                  to={`/country/${country.name}`}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                  <div className="my-card zoom">
                    <img src={country.flag} alt="flag" className="flag" />
                    <h3 className="white-text">{country.name}</h3>
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCountries;
```

Redux action file from where I am making api call

```
export const getAllCountries = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    const res = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_ALL_COUNTRIES",
      payload: res.data,
    });
    dispatch(setLoading(false));
  };
};
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  countries: [],
  countryData: [],
  allCountries: [],
  loading: false,
};

const getCountriesData = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_COUNTRIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        countries: action.payload,
      };
    case "GET_ALL_COUNTRIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        allCountries: action.payload,
      };
    case "GET_COUNTRY_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        countryData: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
      };
    case "CLEAR_STATE": {
      return {
        ...initialState,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default getCountriesData;
```

Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import reducers from "./redux/reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **This is expected behaviour with your current setup**

- First log is in the initial render of your component
- Second log is after the initial render, `useEffect` is trigger follow up with `dispatch(getAllCountries())` causing `dispatch(setLoading(true))` which lead to the 2nd render.
- The third log is when your Axios fetching is done and `GET_ALL_COUNTRIES` is triggered, this changes your state causing 3rd re-render.
- The fourth log is after `GET_ALL_COUNTRIES` is finished and then dispatch(setLoading(false)) is triggered causing loading state change again.

**You can reduce the number of re-render by remove `dispatch(setLoading(false))` and place it in the reducer.**

```
case "GET_COUNTRIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        countries: action.payload,
      };
```

---

**My suggestion with your case is that you should not worry too much about re-render since your component is lightweight and doesn't have any heavy process.**

Comment: Please *never* have a side effect like a dispatch directly in a function component's body. Not only will it happen at every render, it might even happen during renders that do not get committed (because of another component suspending the tree) or by render executions that are only happening in dev mode (in dev mode, React executes render twice)

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Thanks for the prompt reply, really appreciate it.
I removed set loading and placed it in reducer and it reduced on render but if I am placing dispatch(getAllCountries()); outside useEffect hook I am getting this error and my app crash:
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
▶ 28 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: Yah, that was a terrible mistake from me as @phry said. I updated the answer. As I mentioned in the answer, in your case, you should not worry too much about the number of renders.